# Intersection of a sphere with center at (0,0,0) and a plane passing through the this center (0,0,0)

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have been asked to show that the intersection of a sphere and a plane is a circle using two methods, at least this is my interpretation of a problem in a text.

The first method was something to do with hamilton's principle. It resulted in an integral from the pit of hell. I might ask a separate question about these integrals later.

What I am having trouble with at the moment is the more vanilla way of doing this.

I wrote down what I believe to be the equation of a plane.

$ax + by + cz + d = 0$

so in scalar form something familiar like:

$a(x - x_0) + b(y - y_0) + c(z-z_0) = 0$

I just then said the equation of the plane through (0,0,0) is

$x + y + z = 0$

I wrote the equation for a sphere similarly with the center at (0,0,0) to be

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$

I tried to solve for $z$ of the plane, and substitute it into the sphere equation in hopes of getting the equation of a circle.

Something that looks like

$(x-h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = r^2$

This did not happen.

I got

$2x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2 = r^2$

setting r to 1

$2(x^2 + xy +y^2) = 1$

It would seem I can rewrite this as

$(x + y)^2 + x^2 + y^2  = 1$

I don't think I have made any illegal moves. What's going on?

Comment: Are you allowed to choose the plane arbitrarily, or why did you choose your plane equation as $x+y+z=0$? What calculations did you do to obtain your "ellipse equation"?

Comment: The idea is to find a circle whose center lies at the center of a sphere.  I wanted to pick a plane that passes through the center.  We want the plane to contain the point  (0,0,0) I think. I think this is the only requirement.  For  I set a = b = c = 1 to make things simple. I did straightforward algebra to try to get the equation of a circle

Comment: Also, I have now removed  " I seem to get an ellipse" from the post. However, If you set r = 1 you get an ellipse I think

Answer (score 4):

For any plane through the origin, you can rotate the sphere so that the plane has the equation $z=0$. Since rotation of the sphere leaves the sphere fixed, its equation is still $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$

Setting $z=0$, gives $x^2+y^2=r^2$ which is a circle.

Answer (score 2):

$ax+by+cz=0$ is the equation of a plane through the origin. The normal to that plane is $(a,b,c)$.

You've chosen a particular plane $x+y+z=0$ which is a plane through the origin with the normal pointing along the line defined by $x=y=z$. Then clearly $z=-x-y$ and you get $$x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2=r^2\tag{1}$$ as the equation of the circle, but the circle is in a plane at an angle of $45^\circ$ to any of the existing axes. To get that into the form $p^2+q^2=r^2$ you need to rotate $x'=x\cos45+y\sin45$, $y'=y\cos45-x\sin45$, then $z'=z\cos45+x'\sin45$, $x''=x'\cos45-z\sin45$, and then (1) will turn into an equation like $x''^2+y'^2=r^2$.

While that might be a useful exercise to do, you might have been better off picking a plane like $z=0$.